# How to use Action Script file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, actionscript-3

I have a page curl code in Action Script and i want to use that code in my app which is developed using Xcode(Objective c). Can any one tell whether it is possible or not. If possible then please tell me how to do.

The action script code follows

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.GradientType;
    import flash.display.PixelSnapping;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    import asData.clsGlobalConstants;
    import com.DaveLibrary.clsSupport;
    import com.cupcake.Utils;

    public class clsPageTurn extends Sprite 
    {
        private var cMain:clsMain;
        private var gc:clsGlobalConstants;

        private var flipDirection:int;
        private var pageWidth:Number;
        private var pageHeight:Number;
        private var pageWidthHeight:Number;
        private var pivotY:Number;

        private var NextPageLeft:BitmapData;
        private var NextPageRight:BitmapData;

        private var StationaryPage:Sprite;
        private var StationaryPageMask:Sprite;
        private var StationaryPageBitmap:Bitmap;

        private var StationaryShadow:Sprite;
        private var StationaryShadowMask:Sprite;

        private var FlippingPage:Sprite;
        private var FlippingPageBitmap:Bitmap;
        private var FlippingPageMask:Sprite;
        private var FlippingPageBorder:Sprite;

        private var FlippingPageShadow:Sprite;

        private var OutsideShadow:Sprite;
        private var OutsideShadowMask:Sprite;

        private var LeftRect:Rectangle;
        private var RightRect:Rectangle;
        private var LeftPoint:Point;
        private var RightPoint:Point;

        private var StaticLeftRect:Rectangle;
        private var StaticRightRect:Rectangle;
        private var StaticLeftPoint:Point;
        private var StaticRightPoint:Point;

        public var percentage:Number;
        public var useShadows:Boolean = false;

        public function clsPageTurn(Main:clsMain, FlipDirection:int, pWidth:Number = 1366, pHeight:Number = 768, xOffset:Number = -171)
        {
            // constructor code
            cMain = Main;
            gc = cMain.gc;

            this.x = xOffset;

            percentage = 0; // tracks the last percentage that was drawn.

            StationaryPage = new Sprite();
            StationaryPage.x = xOffset;
            this.addChild(StationaryPage);

            StationaryPageBitmap = new Bitmap();
            StationaryPageBitmap.pixelSnapping = PixelSnapping.ALWAYS;
            StationaryPage.addChild(StationaryPageBitmap);

            StationaryPageMask = new Sprite();
            StationaryPageMask.x = xOffset;
            this.addChild(StationaryPageMask);

            useShadows = !clsMain.isSlow;
            if ( useShadows )
            {
                StationaryShadow = new Sprite();
                StationaryShadow.x = xOffset;
                this.addChild(StationaryShadow);

                OutsideShadow = new Sprite();
                OutsideShadow.x = xOffset;
                this.addChild(OutsideShadow);

                OutsideShadowMask = new Sprite();
                OutsideShadowMask.x = xOffset;
                this.addChild(OutsideShadowMask);
            }

            FlippingPage = new Sprite();
            FlippingPage.x = xOffset;
            this.addChild(FlippingPage);

            FlippingPageBitmap = new Bitmap();
            FlippingPageBitmap.pixelSnapping = PixelSnapping.ALWAYS;
            FlippingPage.addChild(FlippingPageBitmap);

            if ( useShadows ) 
            {
                FlippingPageBorder = new Sprite();
                FlippingPage.addChild(FlippingPageBorder);
            }

            FlippingPageMask = new Sprite();
            FlippingPageMask.x = xOffset;
            this.addChild(FlippingPageMask);

            if ( useShadows )
            {
                FlippingPageShadow = new Sprite();
                FlippingPage.addChild(FlippingPageShadow);
            }

            // set the page width and height and other variables for this page flip object.
            pageWidth = pWidth / 2; // the width is the width of one of our half pages, not the full screen width.
            pageHeight = pHeight;
            pageWidthHeight = pageWidth + pageHeight;           
            pivotY = (pageHeight/2) + pageWidth;

            // rect and points for copying the halves.
            LeftRect = new Rectangle(xOffset, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
            RightRect = new Rectangle(pageWidth + xOffset, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
            LeftPoint = new Point(xOffset,0);
            RightPoint = new Point(pageWidth + xOffset, 0); 

            StaticLeftRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
            StaticRightRect = new Rectangle(pageWidth, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
            StaticLeftPoint = new Point(0,0);
            StaticRightPoint = new Point(pageWidth, 0); 

            flipDirection = FlipDirection;

            // create our page halves.
            NextPageLeft = new BitmapData(pageWidth, pageHeight, true, 0);
            NextPageRight = new BitmapData(pageWidth, pageHeight, true, 0); 

            if(flipDirection > 0) {
                StationaryPageBitmap.bitmapData = NextPageRight;
                FlippingPageBitmap.bitmapData = NextPageLeft;
            } else {
                StationaryPageBitmap.bitmapData = NextPageLeft;
                FlippingPageBitmap.bitmapData = NextPageRight;
            }

            // disable the mouse for this sprite so it doesn't trap events.
            this.mouseEnabled = false;
            this.mouseChildren = false;     
        }

        public function destroy():void
        {
            this.graphics.clear();

            if(this.parent != null) {
                if(this.parent.contains(this)) {
                    this.parent.removeChild(this);
                }
            }

            if(NextPageLeft != null) NextPageLeft.dispose();
            NextPageLeft = null;

            if(NextPageRight != null) NextPageRight.dispose();
            NextPageRight = null;

            if(StationaryPage != null) {
                while(StationaryPage.numChildren < 0) {
                    StationaryPage.removeChildAt(0);
                }
            }
            StationaryPage = null;

            if(StationaryPageMask != null) StationaryPageMask.graphics.clear();
            StationaryPageMask = null;

            if(StationaryShadow != null) StationaryShadow.graphics.clear();
            StationaryShadow = null;

            if(StationaryShadowMask != null) StationaryShadowMask.graphics.clear();
            StationaryShadowMask = null;

            if(OutsideShadow != null) {
                while(OutsideShadow.numChildren < 0) {
                    OutsideShadow.removeChildAt(0);
                }
            }
            OutsideShadow = null;

            if(OutsideShadowMask != null) OutsideShadowMask.graphics.clear();
            OutsideShadowMask = null;

            if(FlippingPage != null) {
                while(FlippingPage.numChildren > 0) {
                    FlippingPage.removeChildAt(0);
                }
            }
            FlippingPage = null;

            if(FlippingPageMask != null) FlippingPageMask.graphics.clear();
            FlippingPageMask = null;

            if(FlippingPageShadow != null) FlippingPageShadow.graphics.clear();
            FlippingPageShadow = null;

            if(FlippingPageBitmap != null) {
                if(FlippingPageBitmap.bitmapData != null) FlippingPageBitmap.bitmapData.dispose();
            }
            FlippingPageBitmap = null;

            gc = null;
            cMain = null;
        }

        public function Initialize( NextPage:BitmapData ):void
        {
            NextPageLeft.copyPixels(NextPage, StaticLeftRect, StaticLeftPoint);
            NextPageRight.copyPixels(NextPage, StaticRightRect, StaticLeftPoint);
            StationaryPageBitmap.smoothing = useShadows;
            FlippingPageBitmap.smoothing = useShadows;

            redraw(0);
        }

        public function InitializeDO( NextPage:DisplayObject ):void
        {
            var rect:Rectangle = NextPage.scrollRect;
            NextPage.scrollRect = LeftRect;
            NextPageLeft.draw( NextPage );
            NextPage.scrollRect = RightRect;
            NextPageRight.draw( NextPage );
            NextPage.scrollRect = rect;
            StationaryPageBitmap.smoothing = useShadows;
            FlippingPageBitmap.smoothing = useShadows;

            redraw(0);
        }


        public function InitializeHelperObjects():void
        {
            var bmData:BitmapData;
            var m:Matrix;
            var colors:Array;
            var alphas:Array;
            var ratios:Array;
            var maxLength:Number = Math.sqrt((pageWidth * pageWidth)+(pageWidthHeight * pageWidthHeight));
            var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

            StationaryPageBitmap.x = ((flipDirection * pageWidth) / 2) - (pageWidth / 2);
            StationaryPageBitmap.y = -pivotY - (pageHeight/2);

            StationaryPage.x = pageWidth;
            StationaryPage.y = pivotY + (pageHeight / 2);

            StationaryPageMask.graphics.clear();
            StationaryPageMask.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00,1);
            StationaryPageMask.graphics.drawRect(((flipDirection > 0) ? 0 : -pageWidth)  , (-pivotY) - (pageWidthHeight / 2), pageWidth, pageWidthHeight);
            StationaryPageMask.graphics.endFill();          
            StationaryPageMask.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,pageWidth, pivotY + (pageHeight / 2));

            colors = [gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color, gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color];
            alphas = [0,0,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Stationary_Max,0,0];
            ratios = [0,85,125,170,255];
            matrix = new Matrix();

            if ( useShadows )
            {
                StationaryShadow.graphics.clear();
                StationaryShadow.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
                StationaryShadow.graphics.drawRect(((flipDirection > 0) ? 0 : -pageWidth), (-pivotY) - (pageWidthHeight / 2), pageWidth, pageWidthHeight);
                StationaryShadow.graphics.endFill();            
                StationaryShadow.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,pageWidth, pivotY + (pageHeight / 2));
            }

            FlippingPageBitmap.x = ((-flipDirection * pageWidth) / 2) - (pageWidth / 2);
            FlippingPageBitmap.y = (-pivotY) - (pageHeight / 2);
            FlippingPage.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,pageWidth, pivotY + (pageHeight / 2));

            maxLength = Math.sqrt((pageWidth * pageWidth)+(pageWidthHeight * pageWidthHeight));
            colors = [gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color,gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Color];
            alphas = [0, gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Flipping_Max, gc.pageTurn_InsideShadow_Flipping_Max, 0];
            ratios = [0, 100, 150, 255];
            matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.createGradientBox( pageWidth, FlippingPageBitmap.height, 0, 0, 0);

            if ( useShadows )
            {
                FlippingPageShadow.graphics.clear();
                FlippingPageShadow.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
                FlippingPageShadow.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, FlippingPageBitmap.width, FlippingPageBitmap.height);
                FlippingPageShadow.graphics.endFill();          
                FlippingPageShadow.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,FlippingPageBitmap.x, FlippingPageBitmap.y);       
            }

            FlippingPageMask.graphics.clear();
            FlippingPageMask.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000,1);
            FlippingPageMask.graphics.drawRect(((-flipDirection * pageWidthHeight) / 2) - (pageWidthHeight/2), (-pivotY) - (pageWidthHeight / 2), pageWidthHeight, pageWidthHeight*2);
            FlippingPageMask.graphics.endFill();
            FlippingPageMask.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,pageWidth, pivotY + (pageHeight / 2));

            if ( useShadows )
            {
                OutsideShadow.graphics.clear();
                OutsideShadow.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,cMain.gc.pageTurn_OutsideShadow_Alpha);
                OutsideShadow.graphics.drawRect(FlippingPageBitmap.x, FlippingPageBitmap.y, FlippingPageBitmap.width, FlippingPageBitmap.height);
                OutsideShadow.graphics.endFill();
                OutsideShadow.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,pageWidth, pivotY + (pageHeight / 2));

                OutsideShadowMask.graphics.clear();
                OutsideShadowMask.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,1);
                OutsideShadowMask.graphics.drawRect(((-flipDirection * pageWidthHeight) / 2) - (pageWidthHeight/2), (-pivotY) - (pageWidthHeight / 2), pageWidthHeight, pageWidthHeight*2);
                OutsideShadowMask.graphics.endFill();
                OutsideShadowMask.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,pageWidth, pivotY + (pageHeight / 2));

                FlippingPageBorder.x = FlippingPageBitmap.x;
                FlippingPageBorder.y = FlippingPageBitmap.y;
                FlippingPageBorder.width = pageWidth;
                FlippingPageBorder.height = pageHeight;

                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.clear();
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.beginFill(0x000001, 1);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.drawRect(0,0,gc.pageTurn_Border_Size, pageHeight);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.endFill();
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.beginFill(0x000001, 1);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.drawRect(gc.pageTurn_Border_Size,0,pageWidth-(gc.pageTurn_Border_Size*2), gc.pageTurn_Border_Size);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.endFill();
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.beginFill(0x000001, 1);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.drawRect(gc.pageTurn_Border_Size,pageHeight - gc.pageTurn_Border_Size,pageWidth - (gc.pageTurn_Border_Size*2), gc.pageTurn_Border_Size);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.endFill();
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.beginFill(0x000001, 1);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.drawRect(pageWidth - gc.pageTurn_Border_Size,0,gc.pageTurn_Border_Size, pageHeight);
                FlippingPageBorder.graphics.endFill();
                FlippingPageBorder.visible = true;
            }

            StationaryPage.mask = StationaryPageMask;
            FlippingPage.mask = FlippingPageMask;
            if ( useShadows ) OutsideShadow.mask = OutsideShadowMask;
        }

        public function redraw(Percentage:Number):void
        {
            percentage = Utils.Clamp( Percentage, 0, 1 );

            var rot:Number = flipDirection * 45 * Percentage;

            rotateSprite(FlippingPage, (flipDirection * 90) - rot * 2);

            if ( useShadows )
            {
                FlippingPageShadow.alpha = 0;
                StationaryShadow.alpha = clsSupport.GetBezier2DPercentage(0,0,1,1,Percentage);
                FlippingPageBorder.alpha =  gc.pageTurn_Border_Alpha * (1 - percentage);
                rotateSprite(OutsideShadow, ((flipDirection * 90) - rot * 2) + (clsSupport.GetBezier2DPercentage(gc.pageTurn_OutsideShadow_OffsetStart, gc.pageTurn_OutsideShadow_OffsetEnd, gc.pageTurn_OutsideShadow_LeadIn, gc.pageTurn_OutsideShadow_LeadOut, Percentage) * -flipDirection));
                rotateSprite(StationaryShadow, (flipDirection * 45) - rot );
                rotateSprite(OutsideShadowMask, (flipDirection * 45) - rot);
            }

            rotateSprite(StationaryPageMask, (flipDirection * 45) - rot );          
            rotateSprite(FlippingPageMask, (flipDirection * 45) - rot);

            if(Percentage == 0 && useShadows) 
            {
                FlippingPageBorder.x = FlippingPageBitmap.x;
                FlippingPageBorder.y = FlippingPageBitmap.y;
                FlippingPageBorder.width = FlippingPageBitmap.bitmapData.width;
                FlippingPageBorder.height = FlippingPageBitmap.bitmapData.height;
            }
        }

        private function rotateSprite(spr:Sprite, degress:Number):void
        {
            var m:Matrix;
            var x:Number;
            var y:Number;
            x = spr.x;
            y = spr.y;
            m = spr.transform.matrix;
            m.a = 1;
            m.b = 0;
            m.c = 0;
            m.d = 1;
            m.rotate(clsSupport.ToRadians(degress));
            m.tx = x;
            m.ty = y;
            spr.transform.matrix = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. if you want to use it in objective-c, must directly porting. Note that the page curl effect is built into iOS. To use the code on the iPhone using Air for iOS development.

Comment: I have tried page transitions in iOS. But i need transition exactly like the this video "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA51BDHKTyc&feature=youtu.be".

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIPageViewController to have this curl effect. Set the transitionStyle to *UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl* or use the init-method – *initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options:* .
Create instances of all the viewController you want use in put them into an array. This array is first argument of the *setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:* method.